# QML image does not load image with non ASCII character in image source

Tags: c++, linux, qt, url, qml

I have to show image from USB device on my Linux based device.
My USB has a folder which has a non-ASCII character.
It is replaced by "?" character.

Original path : `"file:///tmp/USB6/§§§§/Koala.jpg"`

and

QML returns error : `"QML Image: Cannot open: file:///tmp/USB6/????/Koala.jpg"`

How will my Image be loaded with this path?

```
Image {
  id: mainImage
  source: iconRole
  asynchronous: true
  sourceSize.width:  screenSize_Width
  sourceSize.height:  screenSize_Height
  fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectCrop
  onSourceChanged: {
     console.log("SOURCE = ",source)
  }
}
```

1. Logs I am getting : `SOURCE = file:///tmp/USB6/§§§§/Koala.jpg`
2. Error I am getting QML Image: `Cannot open: file:///tmp/USB6/????/Koala.jpg`.

Comment: I know you suspect the character and it might be the reason, but as you mentioned USB too, do you have permission to open files in there?

Comment: Yes all permissions are there.
File paths containing ASCII characters are opening properly.

Comment: I see, can you please share the part of you code that opens the file?

Comment: If you bind your image as resource (in qrc) what do you get.

Comment: If I add the file in resource , the also It is not working. I am getting same error.

Comment: Make sure that the usb filesystem is mounted with correct file name encoding, that the qml source is UTF-8 encoded, and that the system locale matches it. Before you even begin working with QML, you should get the time to open correctly using `QFile`.

Comment: if not working when added as resource, given you know ahead that those non Unicode chars are unavoidable, try to get your OS work good for you by creating a link with a neat name towards the target (ln), if your OS works it out, ok, otherwise its out of Qt.

Comment: Its working , in Windows system , but not in Linux system. That's what I guessed that it is related to some Linux setting like "Locale".

Comment: While building on linux machine , I am getting this error,
qml_qtquickcompiler.qrc': Cannot find file 'image/Settings/Common/Tulilk§§§.png'

Comment: I got it's solution , Posted in answer, Thanks for your all support guys.

Answer (score 1):

Qt docs about [URL](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-url.html):

> Additionally, URLs may contain encoded characters using the
> 'percent-encoding' scheme specified by [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986). These characters will
> be preserved within properties of type url, to allow QML code to
> construct precise URL values. An exception to this rule is the
> preemptive decoding of directory-separator characters ('/') - these
> characters are decoded to allow the URL to be correctly classified.
>
> For example, a local file containing a '#' character, which would
> normally be interpreted as the beginning of the URL 'fragment'
> element, can be accessed by encoding the characters of the file name:
>
> ```
> Image { source: encodeURIComponent("/tmp/test#1.png") }
> ```
>
> This basic type is provided by the QML language.

Comment: Does it need any locale to be set for the system?

Comment: @AnupamSrivastava Yes I guessed you can't because it's only mentioned ascii symbols and I think Qt/QML doesn't support what you want to do. I know you can do this with Python using wide characters but I don't think it's possible in Qt.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for this case.

```
QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));
```

Put this statement in main.cpp